# digital-humanities.Rmd deprecated?

Tags: quanteda, vignette

I'm trying to explore the digital-humanities.Rmd available here: https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/blob/5ae204016e1219ab69789b48b44a2ac1b414602a/vignettes/pkgdown/replication/digital-humanities.Rmd

But it seems a part of the code is deprecated because when I knitted it I get this error:

```
Quitting from lines 444-448 [unnamed-chunk-43] (Untitled.Rmd)
Error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'texts' applied to an object of class "c('readtext', 'data.frame')"
Backtrace:
 1. quanteda::texts(readtext::readtext("http://www.gutenberg.org/files/161/161-0.txt"))
Execution halted
```

I've tryed to replace quanteda::texts() by as.character.corpus() as it is recommended in the help information of quanteda::texts():

```
as.character.corpus(readtext::readtext("http://www.gutenberg.org/files/161/161-0.txt"))
Execution halted
```

... but it doesn't work.

Any help to solve this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Fixed now, that vignette was using a defunct usage (`texts()`, which is now `as.character()`). But this should have been a GitHub issue, not a SO question.